# Searchkick: Net::ReadTimeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, searchkick

I recently upgraded my elasticsearch from 1.8 to 2.0 and problems have started since that time. Before it worked like a charm.

When I try to reindex products (40k), I get the Net::ReadTimeout error after 1000 products are reindex (the batch_size is set to 1000 by default).

I tried to set batch_size for searchkick to 1, 100, 200, and even then I get the Net::ReadTimeout error. When it was set to 1, it reindexed almost 20k products, if 100, only 100, if 200 only 200 products when it threw that error.

Do you know why this error occurs and how to avoid it? I have tried so many things (increase timeout from 1 to 10 minutes on the server, delete indexes, set the batch_size many times..) and nothing helped.

I have spent on this already few days and am totally stuck, will appreciate any ideas or help.

Here is the Product model config:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
searchkick settings: {
          number_of_shards: 5,
          analysis: {
            filter: {
              hunspell_CZ: {
                type: 'hunspell',
                locale: 'cs_CZ',
                dedup: true,
                recursion_level: 0
              },
              czechStemmer: {
                type: 'stemmer',
                name: 'czech'
              },
            #  customWordDelimiter: {
            #    type: 'word_delimiter',
            #    generate_word_parts: true,
            #    generate_number_parts: true,
            #    catenate_words: true,
            #    catenate_numbers: true,
            #    catenate_all: true,
            #    split_on_case_change: true,
            #    preserve_original: true,
            #    split_on_numerics: true,
            #    stem_english_possessive: false
            #  },
              customUnique: {
                type: 'unique',
                only_on_same_position: false
              }
            },
            analyzer: {
              myFulltextAnalyzer: {
                type: 'custom',
                tokenizer: 'standard',
                filter: ['lowercase', 'czechStemmer', 'customUnique', 'icu_folding', 'hunspell_CZ'],#'customWordDelimiter',
                char_filter: ['html_strip']
              }
            }
          }
      },
      text_middle: [ :cs_product, :ma_product, :en_product, :cs_description, :en_description, :ma_description ], 
      index_name: "products_v1", 
      merge_mappings: true,
      mappings: {
        product: {
          properties: {
            cs_product: {type: "string", analyzer: "myFulltextAnalyzer", index: "analyzed"},
            en_product: {type: "string", analyzer: "myFulltextAnalyzer", index: "analyzed"},
            ma_product: {type: "string", analyzer: "myFulltextAnalyzer", index: "analyzed"},
            cs_description: {type: "string", analyzer: "myFulltextAnalyzer", index: "analyzed"},
            en_description: {type: "string", analyzer: "myFulltextAnalyzer", index: "analyzed"},
            ma_description: {type: "string", analyzer: "myFulltextAnalyzer", index: "analyzed"}
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Offering money in exchange for answers here is generally frowned upon. Offer a bounty if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks @Undo for the information. I am looking for the bounty, but I have not found a way how to set it for this or even my older posts. Am I missing anything?